# kendo extract data to pdf file asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid, extract

I want to implement the extraction option kendo grid data to a PDF file, I found a solution in kendo forum on the following:

```
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/pdf-export
```

But a script must be installed to Extracte all data

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/pako.min.js")"></script>
```

but I have not found the relevant link to install this script in visual studio 
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I am going to answer and then I am going to close vote on your question.

Your link says:

```
<!-- Load Pako ZLIB library to enable PDF compression -->
```

and

> This page loads pako_deflate.min.js. [...]

Google says:

```
https://github.com/nodeca/pako
```

So all your need files are here:

https://github.com/nodeca/pako/tree/master/dist